# Unable to create, sign, and broadcast eth transaction on ropsten with ledger nano s

Tags: dapp-development

I am unable to successfully sign and broadcast an eth transaction. My code is below.

Sign transaction code:

```
const getTransport = () => TransportU2F.create()
const eth = new AppEth(transport)

const rawTxData = {
  'nonce': '0x01',
  'gasPrice': '0x2cb417800',
  'gasLimit': '0x5208',
  'from': '0x4422D3c22Ec36739713636eca288Ca8ddB0106E9',
  'to': '0x4203b1F04e88C0E8B1b54b0e38065a3d006283D3',
  'value': '0x5af3107a4000',
  'chainId': '3',
  'v': '0x03',
  'r': '0x00',
  's': '0x00'
}

const tx = new EthereumTx(rawTxData)

const result = await eth.signTransaction(
  "44'/60'/0'/2",
  tx.serialize().toString('hex')
)

tx.v = Buffer.from(result.v, 'hex')
tx.r = Buffer.from(result.r, 'hex')
tx.s = Buffer.from(result.s, 'hex')

return tx
```

Broadcast transaction code:

```
const signedTransaction = `0x${signedTx.serialize().toString("hex")}`

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction)
.on('transactionHash', function(hash) {
  console.log('Transaction hash: ' + hash)
  callback(hash)
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt) {
  console.log('Confirmation number: ' + confirmationNumber)
})
.on('receipt', function(receipt) {
  console.log('Receipt: ' + receipt)
})
.on('error', console.error)
```

The transaction is sent out smoothly, but on `ropsten.etherscan.io` the transaction comes up as:

```
Sorry, we are unable to locate this Transaction Hash.
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Any help is much appreciated! I have been stuck on this for days.

Also, are there any full examples out there of creating a raw eth transaction, signing it with the ledger, and broadcasting it to the Ethereum network? I am unable to find any in the ledger documentation or anywhere on github.

Comment: I am running into the same problem. Any luck with this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33977)